# Weird lines during Gnuplotting

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot a 3D figure using Gnuplot, but it gives me some weird lines (valleys) along Y-axis which are not supposed to be there. It seems like my command is not plotting along X-axis properly. And when I change `set dgrid3d 300,300` to other values such as `500,500` or `700,700`, the number of these weird lines changes as well as their positions. My data file has 2084 points in the X-axis and 125 points in the Y-axis. Hope someone can help me on this.

The following is my command:

```
set terminal postscript color
set output "Figure.ps"
unset key
set xlabel "X"
set ylabel "Y"
set zlabel "Z"
set xr [0:2084]
set yr [-.99621756724589383480:1.89823137348250416567]
set zr [0:0.025]
set pm3d
set pm3d interpolate 0,0
set palette defined (20 "black", 40 "green", 55 "blue", 70 "orange", 100 "red")
set cbrange [0:0.025]
set ticslevel 0.0001
set dgrid3d 300,300
set hidden3d
set view 45, 345
splot "data" u 2:1:3 w l
```

and this is the result:

[image: This is the result]

Comment: Can you post your data file as well? Also, `set dgrid3d` makes a weird interpolation of your data unless you use the `splines` option, but I have noticed this to be rather slow compared to the standard algorithm.

Comment: Do you have scattered data? If you data points are gridded you don't need `set dgrid3d`.

Comment: @Miguel  This is my data link: http://files.figshare.com/1593463/data  Thanks.

Comment: @Christoph Actually I am not so clear about scattered or gridded data, my data file is given through this link: http://files.figshare.com/1593463/data Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you actually have the valleys in your data points file.

Comment: @mahmood When I plot the raw data with dots, I can't see those valleys, so I think it's something wrong with my command...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `dgrid3d` settings together with your clipping of higher z-values gives you this totally distorted representation of the data.

Consider the following, simplified plot of your data:

```
set terminal postscript eps
set output 'Figure.ps'

set autoscale xfix
set autoscale yfix
set pm3d
set palette defined (20 "black", 40 "green", 55 "blue", 70 "orange", 100 "red")
set zrange [0:0.3]
set cbrange [0:0.1]
set ticslevel 0
set view 64,104
splot 'data' u 2:1:3 with pm3d notitle
```

This gives the following result (tested with 4.6.5):

[image]

Comment: Hi Christoph, thanks for your reply, it does work. Also I tried to use "set dgrid3d 125,300 gauss 0.1" to plot it, and it's better than what I had before.But your command is much better, cause "set dgrid3d 125,300 gauss 0.1" will lose some of the details.